# What are the minimum resource providers assigned/needed by Azure on a new subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-subscription

I'm working on an application that deploys and configures resources in Azure. This application will be run by clients and I have no way of knowing whether they'll create new subscriptions, or re-use older ones. Accordingly, I'm registering a set of Resource Providers (RPs) before trying to deploy anything.

As part of my testing, I've found all sorts of RPs that seems to be registered by default. Some of them (e.g. "Microsoft.Authorization" or "Microsoft.Portal") seem crucial to the smooth running of a subscription, so I am loath to start messing about with them. There are others that seem more cryptic (e.g. "Microsoft.Features").

Here's the full list I get when creating a new subscription in Azure today:

- Microsoft.ADHybridHealthService
- Microsoft.Advisor
- Microsoft.AlertsManagement
- Microsoft.Authorization
- Microsoft.Billing
- Microsoft.Cdn
- Microsoft.ClassicSubscription
- Microsoft.Commerce
- Microsoft.Consumption
- Microsoft.ContainerRegistry
- Microsoft.CostManagement
- Microsoft.DocumentDB
- Microsoft.Features
- Microsoft.GuestConfiguration
- microsoft.insights (*NB: it has this casing in the portal too*)
- Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering
- Microsoft.PolicyInsights
- Microsoft.Portal
- Microsoft.ResourceGraph
- Microsoft.ResourceHealth
- Microsoft.Resources
- Microsoft.Security
- Microsoft.SerialConsole
- Microsoft.ServiceBus
- Microsoft.Sql
- Microsoft.Storage
- microsoft.support (*NB: another with odd casing*)
- Microsoft.Web

I've no idea if this is standard or can be relied upon. Does it change, for instance, depending on the type of subscription? Or where I'm based?

And which ones are *needed*? I'm pretty certain my subscription will continue to function without the Service Bus, but what about Billing? (I presume it won't make things free...)

To save me having to do a load of trial and error, is there a definitive, canonical list anywhere of the RPs needed for Azure to work properly? Or even just a canonical list of those included on a new subscription by default.

Answer (score 0):

When ever a new Azure Subscription account  is created , list of few Resource providers are available by default.
Some are ***Registered*** and some are ***NotRegistered***

- I have checked with ***free*** and ***pay-as-you-go***  Azure Subscriptions, the list of Registered Providers are different for each subscription

***Ex:*** I can see the    `Microsoft.ServiceBus` as Registered in Pay-as-you-go Subscription and as NotRegistered in Free Azure Subscription

***In Pay-as-you-go Subscription***

[image]

***In Free Trial Subscription***

[image]

To list out the available  Resource Providers have a look at [Available Resource providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers)

Also refer  [How to Enable Azure Resource Providers](https://wedoazure.ie/2020/07/15/how-to-confirm-and-enable-azure-resource-providers/) and [Azure Resource Providers](https://docs.learnondemandsystems.com/guides/cloud-slice/microsoft-azure/azure-resource-providers.md) for more information